# how to make admob work with android version <=3.2?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I just downloaded the latest admob sdk and added it to my app. But it says it needs android 3.2 to compile.
I just want to if my app will work fine on previous android versions and will the ads load on previous android versions?
If yes, then what does the minimum android 3.2 requirement mean?
If no, then how should go about making the ads work on previous android versions?

Comment: You only have to target that API or higher.

Answer (score 2):

you have to give  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />` (4 or whatever version you want your app to be compaitable) in your manifest file to make it compatiable with older versions. can compile using android 3.2 and to make app run on older versions set as min sdk version  in manifest file

or if that doesn't work download admob older version and try.

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully done the integration with 1.6. I think you need to download the prior versions instead of latest one and then have to embed that with your project.